# Automatically download files using selenium and tor

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I am using Tor as my webdriver with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile)
```

It works exactly how its supposed to,but when I try to download a file I get standard pop up asking me where I want to save it and so on. I can't figure out how to deal with them.

I have read several threads on that topic and it seems like

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/pdf')
binary = FirefoxBinary('/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile)
```

should work, but it doesn't.

Anyone knows how I can solve that issue

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

profile = profile = FirefoxProfile('/Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/pdf')

binary = FirefoxBinary('/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,firefox_profile=profile)
```

That works